# WSO2 ESB: adding additional information in Request message

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

I have an incoming request, to which I want to add additional information before sending it to REST service.

My JSON request looks like this

```
{
  "SvcValidateRq": {
    "UserAccountInfo": {
      "UserID": "7c00d769-ae87-42ff-a42c-27f6f61c359d",
      "Password": "23776BD42FEB4F06812F30A01FC7F6FD"
    }
  }
}
```

I want to introduce a new element "Email" : "abc@xyz.com"

Through the Payload mediator I can create a new JSON file, but I am looking for a way, that I do not have to create the entire structure through Payload mediator, but insert something new into the existing request.

Please let me know how it can be achieved.

Answer (score 0):

[Enrich Mediator](https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB500/Enrich+Mediator) should be the best option for this, but unfortunately it supports only XML. So your next options would be [Script Mediator](https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB500/Script+Mediator).

```
<script language="js">
    var payload = mc.getPayloadJSON();
    //modify the json payload
    mc.setPayloadJSON(payload);    
</script>
```